# How do i get all Questions belonging to one Survey?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

First of all im not too experienced with all that DB stuff so pls have mercy on me.
I have 2 entity classes. Survey and Question.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Survey {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String surveyName;

    private int questionCount;

    private String owner;

    private int participant;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy= "survey", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Question {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String question;

    private int index;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable
    private Survey survey;
```

I have a hard time to write the right query to get all Questions which belong to one Survey with HQL. Maybe somebody can give me a hint in the right direction or give me an example how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pls update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get all `Question`s of a `Survey`:

### 1. Traverse a managed association

You modeled a [bidirectional many-to-one association](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/#biManyToOne). So, if you already loaded the `Survey` entity, you can call the `getSurvey()` method on that entity. Hibernate will then generate and execute the query to fetch the Survey entities.
There are several ways to [optimize that if you're experiencing n+1 select issues](https://thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/). But that's a more advanced topic.

### 2. Implement a query

If you don't need the `Survey` entity, it's better to use a JPQL query which only loads the `Survey` entities. JPQL's syntax is very similar to SQL, and I explained it in great details in my [guide to JPQL](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/).
Here is the query that returns all `Survey` entities associated with a `Query`.

```
TypedQuery<Question> q = em.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Survey s JOIN s.question q WHERE s.id = :id", Question.class);
q.setParameter("id", id);
q.getResultList();
```